# Passing data from view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, segue

I have not found an exact solution for my problem. I need to pass data from one view controller to another view controller.  The problem is, that after the segue, the passed string data does not appear in the label.

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segue1") {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ResultsViewController {
            destination.name = correctslabel.text!
```

The second controller: there is just variable and  "name" and a `UIlabel`, which does not show the passed data.

```
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var namelabel: UILabel!
    var name = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        name = namelabel.text!
    }
}
```

I've tried many ways to do it, but none of them worked. Thank you

Finally worked for me to do an override func of it, which meant, that I had to change the sender from AnyObject to Any?.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried this?

```
// ResultsViewController.swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    namelabel.text = name
}
```

Comment: it shows an error: value of optional type "string" not unwrapped

Comment: @TobyV. in the posted code you declare the name-var this way `var name = ""`. Which means there's nothing to unwrap, it's already non-optional. Is it possible, that you've recently changed the declaration to something like  `var name: String? = ""`?

Comment: I use use there namelabel.text = name and the namelabel.text is an optional, so it might be the problem. Do you know by any chance how to make a non-optional of it? Thank you very much

Comment: @TobyV. it's fine to assign non-optional to optional. The problem would emerge if you do opposite. Looks like the code you posted is not up-to-date.

Comment: I added updated code. If you check it, appreciate it. But thank you very much anyways.